# How to install a doorway through a stone wall where a barrel ceiling is on one side

Tags: structural-engineering

We have an old stone built cottage.  We have a garage we are converting to a bathroom.  The garage roof is a barrel brick ceiling.  We need to break through from the house to the garage but need to know how to approach putting a lintel in where the roof is barrelled as to get the door height we would need to remove some bricks from the barrel   any advice or links to articles/you tube videos would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would get a pro to do this.  Preferably one that's bonded and insured, so if *they* manage to screw it up, you're not short one garage.

Answer (score 0):

I would pin each stone/brick above where the lintel will be in a line and support that on both sides.

Then remove and fit as necessary.

Seen it done and seen it in books as well... But the books were older...

You can search on youtube but unless a professional has the time you may not find anything exactly identical.